# What's the difference between homogeneous and heterogeneous sequences in Python?

Tags: python

In Python, the **List** is one type of homogeneous sequences, while the **Tuple** is one type of heterogeneous sequences. But in a List, we still can put arbitrary type of data in it, like `a=[1, 2, 'abc']`. So, what's the real difference between homogeneous and heterogeneous sequences in Python?

Comment: Both lists and tuples can contain instances of different types. The main difference between them is that tuples are immutable. Where did you read lists were homogeneous sequences in Python?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It says that in the docs.

Comment: I've downvoted this because python lists are not in fact homogenous.

Comment: @Marcin: I'm not sure that's an appropriate reason for a downvote.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, it comes up in section [tuples and sequences](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences): *Tuples are immutable, and usually contain an **heterogeneous** sequence of elements that are accessed via unpacking (see later in this section) or indexing (or even by attribute in the case of namedtuples). Lists are mutable, and their elements are usually **homogeneous** and are accessed by iterating over the list.*

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I made a mistake. In the document, it says that "Lists are mutable, and their elements are usually homogeneous and are accessed by iterating over the list." I missed the word "usually" here. You're right, thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Lists and tuples are mostly identical in Python, except that lists are mutable and tuples are immutable.  Both lists and tuples can be either homogeneous or heterogeneous.

If you want sequences with enforced homogeneity, use the `array` module or use NumPy, for example.

### Documentation

From the [Python Documentation for sequence types](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range):

> Lists are mutable sequences, **typically** used to store collections of homogeneous items (where the precise degree of similarity will vary by application).
>
> Tuples are immutable sequences, **typically** used to store collections of heterogeneous data (such as the 2-tuples produced by the enumerate() built-in). Tuples are **also** used for cases where an immutable sequence of homogeneous data is needed (such as allowing storage in a set or dict instance).

Comment: Lists and tuples should not be used interchangeably in most circumstances, while your answer seems to imply the contrary.

Comment: @arshajii: I was very careful to limit my answer to facts about the sequences themselves.  This is not an appropriate place to opine about which type is better.